Sarturday morning cartoon identification
I loved this cartoon back in the day...
Mid 90s Saturday morning thing.
A bunch of teenage American football players that get transported / sucked through a wormhole to some fantasy dimension. 
Each player can transform into a knight but they keep some qualities of their former self so the  massive football player turns into a massive knight with a huge hammer / axe I think.
This ring any bells for anyone? 

Sounds a little like King Arthur and the Knights of Justice.  But that was supposed to be a Pro team.

Ah Johnny Bones!" Good man!!

And shocking surprise here... it was better in my memory

Dungeons And Dragons was the greatest cartoon there ever was!  Until I rewatched it on DVD recently.  I think the phenomenon is quite widespread, unfortunately.

I ordered Dungeons and Dragons on DVD and was sorry I did.

Attempted to watch Skeleton Warriors recently... terrible move.
